# changing from 5.3 to 5.5 php getting SQL Error: 1064 in loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have upgraded from PHP 5.3 to 5.5 I used this code:

```
 foreach($searchArr as $token)
    {


 foreach($longTblDef as $element)
            {



 if (isset($element['th']) && !empty($element['th']))



  $query .= "LOWER(" . $element['td'] . ") 
LIKE '%" . strtolower($token) . "%'";



if (next($longTblDef) && !empty($element['th'])) $query .= " `OR ";                 }`

if (next($searchArr)) $query .= ") AND (";
        }
```

in 5.3 and it worked fine.  Now when I use it in 5.5 I get the message:
SQL Error: 1064 -- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LOWER(cases_tbl.host) LIKE '%dawn%') ORDER BY cases_tbl.rec_id DESC' at line 6[]

This is the query:

```
SELECT
cases_tbl.rec_id AS "cases_tbl.rec_id", 
cases_tbl.date_added AS "cases_tbl.date_added", 
cases_tbl.status AS "cases_tbl.status", 
clients_tbl.client_number AS "clients_tbl.client_number", 
cases_tbl.matter_number AS "cases_tbl.matter_number", 
concat(clients_tbl.client_number, '-', cases_tbl.matter_number) AS "concat(clients_tbl.client_number, '-', cases_tbl.matter_number)", 
cases_tbl.lead_id AS "cases_tbl.lead_id", 
lead_tbl.initials AS "lead_tbl.initials", 
concat(lead_tbl.name_f, ' ', lead_tbl.name_l, ' (', lead_tbl.initials, ')') AS "concat(lead_tbl.name_f, ' ', lead_tbl.name_l, ' (', lead_tbl.initials, ')')", 
cases_tbl.co_lead_id AS "cases_tbl.co_lead_id", 
concat(co_lead_tbl.name_f, ' ', co_lead_tbl.name_l, ' (', co_lead_tbl.initials, ')') AS "concat(co_lead_tbl.name_f, ' ', co_lead_tbl.name_l, ' (', co_lead_tbl.initials, ')')", 
cases_tbl.matter_type_id AS "cases_tbl.matter_type_id", 
matters_tbl.matter_type AS "matters_tbl.matter_type", 
cases_tbl.ref_name AS "cases_tbl.ref_name", 
cases_tbl.client_id AS "cases_tbl.client_id", 
clients_tbl.client_name AS "clients_tbl.client_name", 
cases_tbl.client_ult AS "cases_tbl.client_ult", 
cases_tbl.opposing_lf AS "cases_tbl.opposing_lf", 
cases_tbl.opposing_side AS "cases_tbl.opposing_side", 
cases_tbl.products AS "cases_tbl.products", 
cases_tbl.description AS "cases_tbl.description", 
cases_tbl.rate AS "cases_tbl.rate", 
cases_tbl.servers AS "cases_tbl.servers", 
CONCAT(REPLACE(servers_tbl.server_unc, '/', '/'), LEFT(cases_tbl.ref_name, 1), '/', clients_tbl.client_number, '-', cases_tbl.matter_number, ' ', cases_tbl.ref_name) AS "CONCAT(REPLACE(servers_tbl.server_unc, '/', '/'), LEFT(cases_tbl.ref_name, 1), '/', clients_tbl.client_number, '-', cases_tbl.matter_number, ' ', cases_tbl.ref_name)", 
cases_tbl.tape AS "cases_tbl.tape", 
cases_tbl.date_modified AS "cases_tbl.date_modified", 
cases_tbl.host AS "cases_tbl.host"  

FROM    cases_tbl 
LEFT JOIN clients_tbl on cases_tbl.client_id = clients_tbl.rec_id
LEFT JOIN matters_tbl on cases_tbl.matter_type_id = matters_tbl.rec_id
LEFT JOIN users_tbl as lead_tbl on cases_tbl.lead_id = lead_tbl.rec_id
LEFT JOIN users_tbl as co_lead_tbl on cases_tbl.co_lead_id = co_lead_tbl.rec_id
LEFT JOIN servers_tbl ON cases_tbl.servers = servers_tbl.rec_id

WHERE (

LOWER(cases_tbl.date_added) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.status) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(concat(clients_tbl.client_number, '-', cases_tbl.matter_number)) LIKE '%dawn%' OR LOWER(concat(lead_tbl.name_f, ' ', lead_tbl.name_l, ' (', lead_tbl.initials, ')')) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(concat(co_lead_tbl.name_f, ' ', co_lead_tbl.name_l, ' (', co_lead_tbl.initials, ')')) LIKE '%dawn%' OR LOWER(matters_tbl.matter_type) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.ref_name) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(clients_tbl.client_name) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.client_ult) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.opposing_lf) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.opposing_side) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.products) LIKE '%dawn%' OR LOWER(cases_tbl.description) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(CONCAT(REPLACE(servers_tbl.server_unc, '/', '/'), LEFT(cases_tbl.ref_name, 1), '/', clients_tbl.client_number, '-', cases_tbl.matter_number, ' ', cases_tbl.ref_name)) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.tape) LIKE '%dawn%' OR 
LOWER(cases_tbl.date_modified) LIKE '%dawn%' OR
LOWER(cases_tbl.host) LIKE '%dawn%') 

ORDER BY cases_tbl.rec_id DESC
```

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong here or if there is another way to code the loop that would work in 5.5?
Thank you for any assistance you can provide.
Dawn

Comment: When you print the query instead of executing it in both PHP versions, is there any difference at all?

Comment: The loop executed in PHP 5.5 builds the query with the last “ OR ” missing, what’s casing the SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not coming from PHP 5.2.3 or lower?
Because it looks like starting with PHP 5.2.4, the behaviour of `next` inside `foreach` loops has changed.

I tested this snippet at [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/tVKh4):

```
<?php
$a = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
foreach($a as $b)
{
    var_dump(next($a));
}
```

PHP 5.2.3 and earlier prints:

```
string(1) "2"
string(1) "3"
string(1) "4"
string(1) "5"
bool(false)
```

Whereas PHP 5.2.4-5.6.8 prints:

```
string(1) "3"
string(1) "4"
string(1) "5"
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Instead of returning the next value, it returns the one after the next, which evaluates to `false` one iteration too early.

Maybe 3v4l is not accurate enough with PHP versions, but if you truly come from PHP 5.3, try running the above snippet and see what it gives you.

I have no idea whether this is intended behaviour or not, but it is most certainly the cause of your problem.

If your `$searchArr` and `$longTblDef` arrays have numeric keys, you could use the `$key => $value` form in `foreach` and check if the next element exists with `isset($longTblDef[$key + 1])`, but a universal solution would be to build an array instead of a string and using `implode` on it after the loop:

```
$and = [];
foreach($searchArr as $token)
{
    $or = [];
    foreach($longTblDef as $element)
    {
        if(isset($element['th']) && !empty($element['th']))
        {
            $or[] = "LOWER(".$element['td'].") LIKE '%".strtolower($token)."%'";
        }
    }
    $and[] = implode(' OR ', $or);
}
$query .= implode(') AND (', $and);
```